# Insert random number MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Im trying to count the number of rows in the table and generate random numbers for the field 'random' Now this works:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table;
```

and this works:

```
 UPDATE my_table SET random = FLOOR(6500 * RAND()) + 1;
```

But this doesn't work:

```
UPDATE my_table SET random = FLOOR((SELECT COUNT(*) ) * RAND()) + 1;
```

But this counts the rows as 0 and adds one so all fields have the number one instead of a unique random number.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong would be most helpful.

Comment: How about `UPDATE my_table SET random = FLOOR((SELECT COUNT(*) from my_table ) * RAND()) + 1;`?

Comment: Ye, I think that you are missing `(SELECT COUNT(*) from my_table` as @AmarDuplantier said.

Comment: You missing table name in subquery. But this might cause deadlocks, because you selecting from same table you updating

Comment: This isn't your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700774/inserting-random-numbers-into-a-table-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT @cnt := count(*) FROM my_table;
UPDATE my_table SET random = FLOOR(@cnt * RAND()) + 1;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a896d/4

Answer (score 0):

```
;with randtab
AS
(
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS otCount 
FROM 
    my_table
)
UPDATE my_table 
SET random = FLOOR(randtab.otCount * RAND()) + 1 
from randtab;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE random_fill( IN cnt INT )
BEGIN


fold: LOOP

     IF cnt < 1 THEN
         LEAVE fold;
     END IF;
    UPDATE my_table  SET random =  9 + CEIL( RAND() * 90 ) from randtab;


    SET cnt = cnt - 1;
END LOOP fold;

END$$ 
DELIMIMTER ;
```

And used like this :

```
CALL random_fill(10000);
```